# php & MySQL - allowing users to update their particulars

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm creating a website which allows users to register an account and login with it. 
Now, I would like for them to be able to update their particulars like username and email. 
I've followed a guide [here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/224508-edit-profile-page/) as I happened to be using the same code as him in register.php however it did not work. 
I'm quite a beginner in php so please bear with me! Help is appreciated.

**register.php**

```
    <?php

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
}

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
{
    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
}
else
{
    $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");
    if($registerquery)
    {
        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";
    }
}

?>

<h1>Register</h1>

<p>Please enter your details below to register.</p>

    <form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform" id="registerform">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I enter editprofile.php, the page is blank. this is my **editprofile.php**

```
    <?php
include "base.php";
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))
{

    $nameuser = $_SESSION['username'];
    $checkinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$nameuser'");

    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($checkinfo,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $id = $results['id'];
        $username = $results['username'];
        $email = $results['email'];

    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $editNAME=$_POST['username'];
        $editEMAIL=$_POST['email'];
        $editID=$_POST['id'];

        $editquery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='$editNAME' , email='$editEMAIL'  WHERE id='$editID'");

        if($editquery)
        {
            echo "<b>Success!</b>";
            echo "Your profile was successfully updated. Please click<a href=\"profile.php\"> here </a>to view.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<b>Error</b>";
            echo "<p>Sorry, your profile update failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Edit Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="editprofile.php" name="editform" id="editform"> 
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /></p>
<p>Email Address : <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></p>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
</form>    
</body>
```

Comment: Now would be a really good moment to familiarise yourself with PHP's non-deprecated APIs (PDO/mysqli_) and, crucially, prepared statements.

Comment: please post the error also

Comment: The page is blank because your first condition (`if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) `) is false. Check if they're true and see if they exist (Same with `if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))`)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. noddy's edit worked for me, I realized that I was careless and didn't notice the extra brackets I added. :) thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
include "base.php";
session_start();
?>

<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))     
{

$nameuser = $_SESSION['username'];
$checkinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$nameuser'");

while($results = mysql_fetch_array($checkinfo,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id = $row['id'];
$username = $row['username'];    
$email = $row['email'];
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$editNAME=$_POST['username'];
$editEMAIL=$_POST['email'];
$editID=$_POST['id'];

$editquery = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username='$editNAME' , email='$editEMAIL'  WHERE id='$editID'");

if($editquery)  
    {  
        echo "<b>Success!</b>";  
        echo "Your profile was successfully updated. Please click<a href=\"profile.php\"> here </a>to view.";  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        echo "<b>Error</b>";  
        echo "<p>Sorry, your profile update failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";  
    }  
   }
 }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Edit Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="editprofile.php" name="editform" id="editform"> 
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /></p>
<p>Email Address : <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></p>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
</form>    
</body>
```

> you try this....
>   Not 100% sure but you try..